# Extracting the intercepts for a dependent factor in a model

Tags: r, model

Suppose I fit a model in R like this:

```
model = glm(y ~ x + language, family = binomial, data = data)
```

`language` is a factor variable; the idea is that there's a different intercept for each language.

Here are the `model` coefficients:

```
> coef(model)
  (Intercept)             x  languageen-GB languageen-US    languageja    languageko 
-17.919438297   0.003119914   -0.427067341  -0.613194669   1.406719444   2.402191148 
   languagezh 
  0.894899827
```

One level of the `language` factor (`de`) has been chosen as a baseline, and `(Intercept)` gives the intercept for that baseline. `languageen-GB`, etc., give intercepts as deltas from the baseline intercept.

This code

```
coeffs = coef(model)
intercepts = c("baseline" = 0, tail(coeffs, -2)) + coeffs["(Intercept)"]
names(intercepts) <- levels(data$language)
intercepts
```

pulls out the actual intercepts for each factor level:

```
       de     en-GB     en-US        ja        ko        zh 
-17.91944 -18.34651 -18.53263 -16.51272 -15.51725 -17.02454
```

But it's horrendous code. There must be a nicer way of doing this with model methods or package functions... ?

Edit: one particularly unpleasant part is that the `tail(coeffs, -2)` will break if you change the formula. I suppose some kind of string search could be used here instead.

Comment: You can refit the model with no intercept using formula `y ~ 0 + x + language`. But this is even clumsier. Write a function with that code?

Comment: @RuiBarradas IMO that's actually much nicer than arbitrarily setting a baseline. If you turn it into an answer I'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of having no baseline factor level is to fit a model with no intercept. This is done with a formula like `y ~ 0 + x + .` or by adding `-1` instead of `0`.

```
model2 <- glm(y ~ 0 + ., data, family = binomial)
intercepts2 <- coef(model2)[-1]
names(intercepts2) <- levels(data$language)
intercepts2
#       de     en-GB     en-US 
#15.846295  8.696764  6.562384
```

Now compare with the result posted in the question.

```
model <- glm(y ~ ., data, family = binomial)

coeffs = coef(model)
intercepts = c("baseline" = 0, tail(coeffs, -2)) + coeffs["(Intercept)"]
names(intercepts) <- levels(data$language)
intercepts
#       de     en-GB     en-US 
#15.846295  8.696764  6.562384 

all.equal(intercepts, intercepts2)
#[1] TRUE
```

The results are not `identical()`, the computations are made in different ways:

```
intercepts - intercepts2
#          de        en-GB        en-US 
#3.197442e-14 3.907985e-14 3.552714e-14
```

**Data creation code.**

I will adapt built in dataset `iris` as a data example.

```
data <- iris[c(1,2,5)]
data$y <- +(data[[1]] < 5.8)
data <- data[-1]
names(data)[c(1,2)] <- c('x', 'language')
i1 <- data[[2]] == "setosa"
i2 <- data[[2]] == "versicolor"
i3 <- data[[2]] == "virginica"
data[[2]] <- as.character(data[[2]])
data[[2]][i1] <- 'de'
data[[2]][i2] <- 'en-GB'
data[[2]][i3] <- 'en-US'
data[[2]] <- factor(data[[2]])
```

Comment: I can live with a 10^{-14} discrepancy!